# Splash Payrix Merchant ID and Portal Credentials

Tags: api, key, splash-screen

i have referred the following links, but not get any clear idea or information where to get the merchant ID and Api keys . Kindly Help me in this regards

https://portal.payrix.com/docs/index

https://portal.splashpayments.com/docs/api

Comment: anyone implemented the splash now known as payrix kindly share the views and thoughts in that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend reaching out to sales@payrix.com if you don't already have a relationship manager so that you can be assigned an Implementation Resource. The Implementation team assists with technical questions related to integrating with the Payrix platform/API including creating a merchant, creating an API key, and getting access to our sandbox environment.